# Userform listbox click code does not trigger

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform in Excel 2016 with two ListBoxes, using the Tools menu. I double clicked them to create subs and inserted code to check whenever one is selected.

Here is the code:

```
Private sub SaleType_Click () 
    If SaleType.Value ="Core" then
        'make sale label visible
        QTDV.visible =true
        ' show core option btn
        Core.Visible = true
    End if
End sub
```

When I have a ListBox created from the toolbox this works, but every other time the form is run the saletype ListBox will be value null and this is a problem because I have a check to make sure the ListBox is not empty. Code follows:

```
If saletype = "" then  
    Dim msg as string Msg = " please select sale type"  
    Msgbox msg, and vbcritical
End if
```

If the ListBox presents value `null` it will not see it as empty and skip the check if I try `saletype = null` it still skips it.

I searched and it seems creating ListBoxes on the tool box is weird because Excel does not know what kind of control it is. I opted for creating the ListBoxes in VBA.

```
Private sub userform_initialize()
    Dim saletype as msforms.Listbox
    Set saletype = me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1", "SaleType")
```

But when running the form and selecting any option on the ListBox the `SaleType_Click` sub does not trigger.

Comment: If you create your listbox in vba try to declare it as Dim WithEvents saletype as msforms.Listbox and see if it works.

Comment: Hi thank for your reply adding withevents to the dim returns a error invalid attribute in sub or form

Comment: Okay moved the variable fr inside the sub to outside and it solved it 8t now triggers the events but now the if saletype. Value = "" always shows as null.

Comment: Use the IsNull function to check for NULL.

Comment: To clarify if I select any value from the listbox it shows it in saletype.Value but if I select nothing it shows null

Comment: Laczko it says object required when I do that BTW I tried if saletype is null then the I tried if saletype isnull and it says compile error expected then or go expected

Comment: It is normal if you select nothing then the variable/property is NULL, as it is not set. You should be able to validate it like this: If IsNull (saletype.Value)  then

Comment: Edited ohhh silly me so that's how isnull is used I'm sorry I'm a noob THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE

Comment: OK, I sum it in an answer so the question will not be visible as unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement event handling (like SaleType_Click) you need to declare the object with the WithEvents keyword:

```
Dim WithEvents saletype as msforms.Listbox
```

And if a variable/property is not set then its value doesn't exist, so instead of empty string ("") you need to validate for NULL - the IsNull function can do that (= NULL doesn't work as = only works with values):

```
If IsNull (saletype.Value) then
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem with my listbox_Click not being fired "every other time".  Maybe it was when the same selection was desired twice in a row.  Anyway, put this in the sheet code for the sheet that is "Show"ing the userform:

```
  userformXXX.listboxYYY.ListIndex = -1
  userformXXX.Show
```

This doesn't work if it is in the userform code.